# Can I put my battery in the middle of my parallel circuit?

Tags: led, circuit-design, battery-operated

This is a small project, basically cosplay, four 5mm LEDs wired in parallel. Normally, I put the battery at the end:
[image: Battery at the end of parallel circuit]

But could I put the battery in the middle with the same result? I'm researching simple circuits but couldn't find theory on placing a battery (3.7V Li-Ion battery). This layout helps me fit the LEDs in a smaller space without extra wire. Any online resources appreciated.

[image: Battery centered in parallel circuit]

Comment: At your level, you can treat all points along the same piece of wire as being the same point in space.

Comment: As they said. | There is an excellent and very intuitive schematic editor provided by the site. Edit your question. PLay. You'll like it. | eg type LED in selection box at top left. Click and drag LED to where you want it. Repeat 3 more times. R rotates in 90 degree steps.| H flips horizontally. | Type /RES - resistor will appear. ['/' effectively takes cursor back to selection box]. Drag resistors to where you want them. |  Clock on component lead ends and drag to get wiring. | Wheeeeeee! | Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two circuits shown are exactly the same. Both use parallel connection of four sets of LED plus resistor and battery. Placing battery at top, middle, or bottom (or anywhere in between) while leaving the same connections unchanged will give the same result. This is because for parallel connection,  the battery’s connected to the same points. You can see this by moving your fingers over the two places where battery is connected and see that they are in fact the same points on the wire. If you want to save wire length or optimal placement of battery then by all means keep battery in middle as long as you keep it connected to same points shown in your picture. For examples of circuits that are similar, I’d just recommend googling “parallel led circuits”.

Answer (score 1):

For simple low-current circuits such as you show, if things are connected in parallel, you may place them in any arrangement you want.

If there are some high-current loads and some low-current loads, you may need to  arrange the wiring so that the high currents don't flow by the low current loads but you are not likely to run into that situation in simple circuits.